# textangular not showing 'break link' icon

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome, textangular

I'm using latest version of [textangular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular).

Everything is working fine and all the icons are showing properly, except for the 'break link' icon, which shows as an empty square.

When i inspect the element i can see that the appropriate classes are applied: `fa fa-unlink icon-unlink`

Any idea what can cause that?

[image]